# Remove lines that contain certain string in Hebrew from a srt subtitles file

Tags: batch-file, line, words

I'm trying to read a text from a subtitles file, read the lines and delete lines that contain specific string (in this case '`היי`' and '`שלום`').

The Idea is that while opening the file, it will let the user to choose a folder in which it will go over all the `*.srt` files and delete the lines containing the specific text.

The general idea is:

1. have a list\array of "bad words"
2. While clicking the program\file it will let the user to select a directory.
3. it will search for each file in the directory and each line at the file if it has one (or more) of the "bad words".

3.1. if it does - it will delete this specific line.

Would like to have it written in batch programming language, yet I'm not sure how to do so. I hope what I have requested is possible and really appreciate any help you can provide.

---

So far, I made a code that let you select a directory:

```
@if (@CodeSection == @Batch) @then


@echo off
setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion

rem Select the folder via WSH Shell.Application BrowseForFolder method
for /F "delims=" %%a in ('cscript //nologo //E:JScript "%~F0"') do set "folder=%%a"
if not defined folder goto :EOF
cd "%folder%"

goto :EOF
@end


// JScript section

var shl = new ActiveXObject("Shell.Application");
var folder = shl.BrowseForFolder(0, "Please choose a folder.\nThis extension will add a \".HebSubs-Tvil.Me\" suffix to each file of the following types: *.ASS; *.AVI; *.MKV; *.MP4", 0, 0x00);
WSH.echo(folder ? folder.self.path : "");
```

Comment: At a glance, I'm just going to say "batch can't do that".  It's a good job for `bash` and `grep`.  If you're stuck in Windows, consider cygwin/bash or maybe Powershell with some kind of `grep` substitute.

Comment: @JuanTomas Is there any chance to get help from you about it in private? I have no idea how to use Bash. Would appreciate any kind of help.

Comment: This might be done even with pure batch code, but this depends on the used encoding of the `*.srt` files. Are the files UTF-16 LE encoded with or without BOM, or are they encoded with UTF-8, or are they encoded using code page 862, or using ISO/IEC 8859-8? The text file encoding is most important here independent on which scripting language or which commands are used for this task.